# The All famous SA login in SQLSERVER : Can it be enabled differently?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, project

For my final year project, I'm making what I call - `SeeQuaL` and it's a one stop interface for accessing 3 of the most famous database types - **SQLite, SQL Server and MySql**. I'm Pretty sure that I can get things done with the SQLite and MySql. But SQL Server, meh! will surely give me problems.

Now lets take the case that I have SQL Server Express 2005 installed on my system but **I don't have** Management studio installed. In order to access my databases , I will need to log in with the SQL server authentication mode `AKA via the all famous login - SA.`

> **So here is my Question:**
>
> > How do I enable this account (*sa*) and set the server authentication to **"SQL Server and Windows authentication"** mode **WITHOUT** using management studio??

I have no idea as to how to accomplish this :( So please help me guys ! Is there some table that I need to access thro the windows authentication mode by which I can get this job done ?

Comment: Why do you require login via sa?  This is more insecure than integrated security.  It sounds like you've taken on a project without really understanding the requirements of people that use MSSQL.

Comment: hmm @.@ well, i've always used the 'sa' login. Would you please expand more so that i understand ? Or link me to a place where i can understand ?

Comment: There are indeed a lot of misunderstandings behind that "Naturally"... in most big companies the "sa" account is inaccessible. Any designated user can be ad admin, but why do you even *need* that; **any** valid user should be able to connect...

Comment: @Marc: well i'm sorry for not being specific. For me in order to access databases, i need to log in using the SA login and is there a workaround for enabling the sa login as well as setting the mode to "SQL server and windows authentication" mode?

Comment: @Skun - but **why** do you need to log in as "sa"? - the premise seems fundamentally flawed. The only reasons for **requiring** sa involve scenarios that involve dubious intent.

Comment: well, how else are you going to connect to a MSSQL server db from lets say a C# program ? Dont you need the SQL server authentication to do that ? ._. excuse me this stoopid question, but my sir always said "there is no such thing as a stoopid question" :P

Comment: You get the administrator of the server to create a new username and password for you, which you use from your C# program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are writing something that pretends to be a replacement for Management Studio, learn what Management Studio does in the first place.

You can trap almost everything Management Studio does using Script button dropdon and selecting "Script Action to New Query Window" at the top of the dialog window after doing the actions you want but just before pressing the Ok button.

Here is the SQL code that is used by Management Studio to do what you are asking for:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
GO
```

Another option is using Profiler.
It's included in Developer Edition.

Comment: wow o.O how'd you do that ? Can you please elaborate? I will check this out. if it works, You've saved my project ! ^o^

Comment: Thanks a million mate. This "script action..." thing is indeed such a powerful tool ! :D You've saved my project ! :)

Answer (score 4):

I think I can give you the answer, because I've just solved it recent days.

To "SQL Server and Windows authentication" mode WITHOUT using management studio, the answer is plain simple except M$ does not want to tell you explicitly.

Expand registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer
```

there you will see a REG_DWORD value named **LoginMode** , if 1 it is Windows Authentication, if 2, it is Windows+SQL Authentication. What you need to do is changing it from 1 to 2 and restart SQLEXPRESS services.

One more thing to do, to enable sa and set its password, which is disabled by default.

Right on you SQL express machine, login to you SQLEXPRESS services instance with command

```
sqlcmd -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS
```

then exeucte

```
1> ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;
2> ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = 'mypassword' ;
3> GO
```

Now you're done.

I learned these from the following URL:

- http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

Comment: Well, after I've read George Polevoy's reply, I realized he has already answered your question perfectly. What a guru.

Answer (score 0):

First off are you running Windows? If so what version? I'm going to assume your running Windows 7, but from memory the steps are the same for Vista

1. Bite the bullet and download [SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en)
2. After you've installed SMSE, Right click on the SMSE link in your start menu and click "Administrator".
3. Connect to your local SQLEXPRESS installation using Windows Authentication.
4. In Object Explorer, Right Click on your SQLEXPRESS instance and select "Properties"
5. Click on Security and select "SQL Server & Windows Authentication mode" and click OK
6. Expand Security > Logins and then right click on your "sa" user, and select properties.
7. Set the "sa" users password to something you'll remember, I suggest using a [Passphrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passphrase) rather than a password.
8. Click OK, and you should be good to go..

You can test by closing and re-opening SMSE without Administrator privileges and try connecting with your SA information.

Comment: well i know how to do it with the management studio. But my application is a small replacement to the management studio. Which means when a person downloads my application, he should be able to create/open a database using the SA login.

Comment: I cant expect that person to have downloaded Management studio and first enable the SA login can i ._.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to that effect. 

Either way, your going to need to connect to the database using Windows Authentication before you can change the Authentication mode.

Comment: will do so. Do you have an idea as to how to change the authentication modes ?